# wlan0 missing and wifi menu not shown in fedora

Tags: fedora, network-interface

I installed XFCE recently on Fedora and after days when I logged in I just found that my Wi-Fi doesn't connect. After that I logged in via GNO<E and actually I have the same trouble.

I used `iwconfig` and output was:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eno1      no wireless extensions.
virbr0    no wireless extensions.
virbr0-nic  no wireless extensions.
```

Also I used `nmcli device show wlan0` command and it says there is no `wlan0` there. Right now I'm using Ethernet and is all that's available. Perhaps my laptop wireless card maybe broken?

BTW, if it helps I have to say in past when I used to connect to VPN, if laptop suspends the same thing happened. One other thing, I used Fedora live and it doesn't show me the Wi-Fi menu or `wlan0` either.

Comment: Do you see the wireless device with `ip l`?  ... or with `lspci` or `lsusb`?

Comment: do as @rickhg12hs said... then, we can say what's going on... `ip link show`...